# R repeat or loop for data.frame to accommodate Multi Lines per row

Tags: r, matrix, repeat, data-manipulation, multiline

Appreciate your help on this. Been working on this for the whole day with no end in sight.

I have a csv file with rows coming through as multi-line per rows. Would like to expand the rest of the columns to accommodate the 'multi' rows.

I tried

## Here is an example

```
df <- data.frame(email = c('email1@email.com','email2@email.com','email3@email.com'),
                    ip = c('1 1 2 2 3','2 2 2','3 3 3'),
                    other = c('x','y','z'))

#looks likes this
             email        ip other
1 email1@email.com 1 1 2 2 3     x
2 email2@email.com     2 2 2     y
3 email3@email.com     3 3 3     z
```

## desired outcome

```
> df_to_be
              email ip other
1  email1@email.com  1     x
2  email1@email.com  1     x
3  email1@email.com  2     x
4  email1@email.com  2     x
5  email1@email.com  3     x
6  email2@email.com  2     y
7  email2@email.com  2     y
8  email2@email.com  2     y
9  email3@email.com  3     z
10 email3@email.com  3     z
11 email3@email.com  3     z
```

## logic to construct

Email1 repeats 5 times due to the number of 'multi' lines for the first row.
Email2 repeats 3 times due to the number of 'multi' lines for the 2nd row.
Email3 repeats 3 times due to the number of 'multi' lines for the 3rd row.

similarly to other column

## My Attempts

```
#function to recreate table based on new row count
repFunc <- function(df, multi_row_c){
  cols_rep <- names(df[which(!names(df) %in% c(multi_row_c))]) #columns to repeat
  vec_rep = str_count(df[,multi_row_c],coll(" "))+1 #vector of number of repeats per row for multi_row_c
  r1 = 1:nrow(df) #row index to repeat
  print('column names to repeat')
  print(cols_rep)
  print('number of repeats per row')
  print(vec_rep)
  print('row index to repeat')
  print(r1) 
  for (i in 1:length(cols_rep)) {
    print(df[,cols_rep[i]])
    # o<-rep(df[r1,cols_rep[i]],vec_rep)
  }
  # return(o)
}

repFunc(df,'ip')
```

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>%  separate_rows(ip)`

Comment: you beauty! pop that in as a solution and i'd put a thumbs up for ya

Comment: thanks..but this has been asked before so I marked it as duplicate of the original question.